# Getting the paths with parameters between valid pages of a web application?

Tags: php, graph, web-applications, doxygen, code-analysis

Suppose that we have a simple web app consists of following valid pages:

```
login.php  (params: username, password)
index.php  (params: product_id)
product.php
```

When we enter the `username` and `password` in the `login.php` page, we will go to the `index.php` page. Now, when we we enter a number in the `product_id` field in the `index.php` page, we will go to the `product.php` page. So, the structure of the web app is:

```
login.php ---(username, password)---> index.php ---(product_id)---> product.php
```

In other words, I want something like this in a graph or any structure:

[image: Structure of the simple web app]

I used [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) (Version: 1.8.13), although it gave me all classes and functions relation, call graph, etc., but it didn't give me the structure between the pages. I would like to know is it possible to do it with `doxygen` or is there a tool, something like a php code analyzer, call graph, control flow and so forth, to give me this structure using the web app source code?

Comment: Please supply a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I.e at least 2, small, files showing how a jump occurs from one to another page, the differences in the Doxyfile compared to the standard Doxyfile and the version of doxygen, (you probably used 1.8.14).

Comment: Cross posted from: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/49828/getting-the-paths-between-valid-pages-of-a-web-application

Comment: It is clear what you want, we need some, minimal working,  code so we can see what is possible (ther might be some other possibilities as well e.g a custom script with grep / sed / dot etc.).

Comment: First line of each PHP file writes its name to a text file, then feed that to GraphViz. QED (if you own the code, of course).